# arcmap export layer as a image with different scale

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, export, image

In our web application, we load too many layers cause the map loading very slow. I am thinking  of export some static layers as images with different scale. There are totally 10 scales in our application, hence I want to export 10 images for a static layer (each scale 1 image). When the application load map data, I only load the image file for the static layer. When the map zoom, I will change different image according to the zooming scale.

I am using arcmap 10.2.

I feel it can be performed, but I haven't get the way to do it. Please advise me, thanks.

Comment: the idea is to build pyramid, which does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the ArcGIS Help 10.2 there is a page called [Managing the performance of ArcGIS map services](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00sp00000012000000) which discusses options for addressing any display performance issues and includes the approach that you mention in your question:

> Precompute information results when you can do so. For example, you
>   can precompute the maps that are delivered with ArcGIS for Server and
>   use cached map services or basemap layers.